# Force page style on all pages

Tags: table-of-contents, footer, pagestyle

In my document I want all my headers and footers to be the same, so I use this code for that purpose:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{Manuel Alonso Cousido}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{History}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
```

However, only some pages display the headers and footers. The first page of each chapter and the TOC pages have no header nor footer.

Do I have to use `\thispagestyle{fancy}` for every first page of chaper? In that case, how can I ensure that all the TOC pages get a footer and a header?

Comment: Usually, `chapter` start pages use `\thispagestyle{plain}`. , so by redefining `plain` it should do what you want. `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}` should work as well

Answer (score 2):

You can use pagestyle `fancyplain` instead `fancy` to get the same header and footer for `plain` and `fancy` pages. If there should be a headrule on `plain` pages too, redefine `\plainheadrulewidth`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}% <- pagestyle fancyplain
\renewcommand\plainheadrulewidth{.4pt}% headrule on plain pages
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{Manuel Alonso Cousido}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{History}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\leftmark}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

If there should be different entries for `plain` and `fancy` pages use `\fancyplain`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}% <- pagestyle fancyplain
\renewcommand\plainheadrulewidth{.4pt}% headrule on plain pages
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{Manuel Alonso Cousido}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{History}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\leftmark}

\fancyhead[C]{\fancyplain{plain page}{fancy page}}% <- added

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]